# Titles in one CSV, Hyperlinks in other CSV, create new CSV with links built in

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have plain text titles in one .csv and hyperlinks for those titles in another .csv

I currently open them in the same work book, put the titles in A, the hyperlinks in H, and use

```
=HYPERLINK(H1,A1)
```

to get my final output of Titles with hyperlinks built in.

Is there an easy way (Excel VBA or macro) to bypass the manual work and create a new output file with the "Titles with hyperlinks built in" from the original two .csv files?

Edit: My two .csv files have the respective text (hyperlink and titles) all down column A.

Comment: What is the format of each .csv? Is there anything on each line besides the titles/hyperlinks?

Comment: My .csv files have the respective text (hyperlink and titles) all down column A.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub buildlinks()
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:/path/Links.csv")
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:/path/Titles.csv")

i = 1
Do Until wb1.Sheets("Sheet1Name").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1Name").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & wb1.Sheets("Sheet1Name").Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & wb2.Sheets("Sheet1Name").Cells(i, 1).Value & ")"
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message: **Compile error: Method or data member not found** and it highlights _.Cells_ of **ThisWorkbook.Cells(i, 1).Formula =**

Comment: also to be clear, on the **Do Until wb1.Sheets("Sheet1Name").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""** I'm entering an integer of how many cells I want it to do this for correct?

Comment: Edited code. And no, you're not entering anything for the integer. You just need to make sure your paths and sheet names are correct.

Comment: my pathnames are correct, I'm not sure what sheet name needs to be but it's now giving this error **run-time error '9': subscript out of range**

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. CSV files are text-only and do not permit hyperlinks. There is no way to create a text or CSV file with clickable links. The only way to have a file with a "built-in hyperlink" is if the file's format is HTML or some other similar format that allows hyperlinks, such as an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create the hyperlinks in the current spreadsheet instead of creating a separate file.

Since you've said that the inputs are really just text files, one item per line, not comma-separated, it's actually pretty simple to implement using the VBA file handling commands.

```
Sub BuildLinks(titlesFilePath as String, linksFilePath As String, ByVal rowStart As Long)
  Dim tf As Long, lf As Long, of As Long
  tf = FreeFile
  On Error Goto NO_TITLE_FILE
  Open titlesFilePath For Input As #tf
  lf = FreeFile
  On Error Goto NO_LINKS_FILE
  Open linksFilePath For Input As #lf
  On Error Goto 0

  While Not (EOF(tf) Or EOF(lf))
    Dim curTitle As String, curLink As String
    Line Input #tf, curTitle
    Line Input #lf, curLink
    Cells(rowStart, 1).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & curLink & """,""" & curTitle & """)"
  Wend
  Close #tf
  Close #lf
  Exit Sub
NO_TITLE_FILE:
  MsgBox "Can't Open Title File" & titlesFilePath
  Exit Sub
NO_LINKS_FILE:
  MsgBox "Can't Open Links File" & linksFilePath
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help. What you offered helped me learn some VBA for the first time by really looking into it. It's still not working but I think this is a step in the right direction. Where exactly do I enter the file path for the links and texts (please indicate with something like this -> **bold**"C:\Users\yourpathhere"**bold** or **C:\yourpathhere**

Comment: You enter the path name in the code that calls `BuildLinks`. Either from immediate mode (control-G) or by writing another `Sub` that you then call, for instance `BuildLinks "c:\users\PathToTitlesFile", "c:\users\PathToLinksFile", 2`

Comment: in the code above that you submitted, is there somewhere inside that code in which I am supposed to enter the actual paths to my files?

Comment: No. You have to write another `Sub` that calls into this `Sub` with the path as a parameter (or call into this one from immediate mode).

Comment: It seems inefficient to have a sub call another sub, to then call the 2 path names.  In the example code offered by @nwhaught there are path names within the sub, but that particular one is giving me errors. In any case, would you be able to post the sub needed to call the paths as you suggested? Would launching the inital vbs (or sub) automatically then create the output file I require?

Comment: The reason I wrote it that way was so that you could call it with any path names. It's not "inefficient". How do you normally call subs? Are you familiar with the Immediate pane (by pressing control-G)? It allows you to call subs by typing their name, whether or not they require parameters.